# Compute Conjugate Gradient using Eigen library

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

I writed the following C++ code to compute the conjugate gradient of a specific matrix, compiler is CMake 3.6.2 in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
ConjugateGradient<SparseMatrix<double>, Lower|Upper> cg;
cg.setMaxIterations(60);
cg.compute(A);
SparseMatrix<double> beta;
beta = cg.solve(logP);
```

It take limitless time to run and does not stop. However, if I change the last line into:

```
cg.solve(logP);
```

the code can run and terminate, but I can't get the result of the computation. A and logP are both SparseMatrix. How should I get the result of the solve() function?

Changing the type of the result object "beta" into MatrixXd leads to the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

while changing the type into  VectorXd leads to:

```
void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::resizeLike(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Solve<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<do‌​uble>, 3>, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>]: Assertion `other.rows() == 1 || other.cols() == 1' failed.
```

So I think the key problem is what type should "beta" be.

Comment: Can you add more information, like a [mcve]? Also, please include info such as: compiler; compiler flags; OS; architecture; and anything else you can think of that is needed to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I never used that lib and this really looks strange, but you should really try to make beta not sparse! Use ```VectorXd``` or whatever is available. (I can imagine, that there is a lot of calculation and memory-management be done in the sparse-case).

Comment: @AviGinsburg THank you, I will edit my question

Comment: @sascha Changing SparseMatrix into VectorXd result in the following problem: void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::resizeLike(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Solve<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>, 3>, Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> >; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1>]: Assertion `other.rows() == 1 || other.cols() == 1' failed.

Comment: As i said. I'm not familar with Eigen. Look for a dense-equivalent of ```SparseMatrix<double>```. (I was under the impression the result-vec is 1d. If it's not, well, dense can be a problem for sure. But i don't know your dimensions.

Comment: @sascha The result-vec is 1d.

Comment: After your edit: ```MatrixXd``` seems to be what i proposed. But it also looks like you do not have enough memory (can try float inst of double). So it's a case of *we don't know the dimensions; how big is the data*. Sadly: dense seems to be not possible with your RAM and sparse either needs much more resources OR uses much more resources and will also bloat your RAM if the result is not sparse which i would suspect. I don't see any huge error in usage here, but again, i'm not an Eigen user. So show the dimensions of your data and do some memory-calculations in your head on what to expect.